# How to fix "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'" while doing Image classification using python

Tags: python, image-processing, keras

I am doing Image Classification using Keras and while training the model I am getting an error which says that "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '**array_interface**'" and it is being generated from Image.py file of PIL and because of which my model is not getting started for training.

I have already tried to do some changes in Image.py file and in my code file but, the error still exists. The code file was working earlier but now it is throwing me an "AttributeError".

```
img_width, img_height = 150, 150
train_dir = r'D:\DataSets\Cats_Dogs\train'
validation_dir = r'D:\DataSets\Cats_Dogs\test'
nb_train_samples = 5000
nb_validation_samples = 1000
epochs = 50
batch_size = 20

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True,
                                   vertical_flip=True, rotation_range=0.2)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, target_size=(img_width, img_height)
                                                    , batch_size=batch_size, class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_dir, target_size=(img_width, img_height)
                                                        , batch_size=batch_size, class_mode='binary')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch= nb_train_samples // batch_size, epochs=epochs,validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps= nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

Use tf.cast instead.
Epoch 1/50
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/ImageClassification/BinaryClass.py", line 56, in <module>
    validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps= nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1658, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 181, in fit_generator
    generator_output = next(output_generator)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 616, in get
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 603, in get
    inputs = future.get(timeout=30)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 406, in get_index
    return _SHARED_SEQUENCES[uid][i]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", line 65, in __getitem__
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", line 230, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
    interpolation=self.interpolation)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py", line 110, in load_img
    img = pil_image.fromarray(path)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2643, in fromarray
    arr = obj.__array_interface__
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

In the code, I am giving the path of my training and testing dataset and at the time of making a model fit on training and validation dataset, it is giving me an error.

Comment: What is the data type of your image for validation? I guess your images are stored in np.ndarray where spaces are filled with `\n`.